# list(), if and short-circuit evaluation

Tags: php, if-statement, short-circuiting

I have the following code snipplet:

```
$active_from = '31-12-2009';
if(list($day, $month, $year) = explode('-', $active_from) 
    && !checkdate($month, $day, $year)) {
    echo 'test';
}
```

Why do I get an undefined variable error?

`list($day, $month, $year) = explode('-', $active_from)` returns `true`, so `list()` is evaluated, isn't it? I think, the variables should be defined? What do I oversee?

This does in my opinion the same and throws no error:

```
$active_from = '31-12-2009';
list($day, $month, $year) = explode('-', $active_from);
if(checkdate($month, $day, $year)) {
    echo 'test';
}
```

This raises no error:

```
if((list($day, $month, $year) = explode('-', $active_from)) && checkdate($month, $day, $year)) {
```

But I really don't understand why :-)

Thanks for explanation

Comment: no errors here http://codepad.org/33BV3EsO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue of [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php), in your case, the `&&` evaluates before the `=`, leading to the errors you describe.

You can resolve this problem by placing the assignment statement inside of a parentheses.

Explicitly, your code should read

```
if(  (list($day, $month, $year) = explode('-', $active_from))
     && !checkdate($month, $day, $year)) {
```

Note that I have changed it from `if( $a=$b && $c )` to `if( ($a=$b) && $c )`. The parentheses force the assignment operator (`=`) to evaluate before the conjunction (`&&`), which is what you want.

Comment: No problem, @FabianBlechschmidt. (And Happy New Year ;-) )

Answer (score 1):

Read about [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php).

```
if ( list($day, $month, $year) = explode('-', $active_from) && !checkdate($month, $day, $year) ) {
```

is identical to

```
if ( list($day, $month, $year) = (explode('-', $active_from) && !checkdate($month, $day, $year)) ) {
```